# Is there a function for adding/showing the UITabBar programmatically?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am building a support type app and need to display my UITab bar across several different pages.

My 'UITabBar Controller' is linked to three other controllers, called "Discover", "Support" and "Contact us". My issue is that the "support" page, has one extra view controller it links to and I can't get the tab bar to display on this secondary (child?) view controller as well as the original "Support" one.

[image]

My segue code is as follows;

```
@IBAction func homeSupportButton(_ sender: Any) { 
    print("Home Support Pressed") 
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeSupport", sender: self)

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let homeController = segue.destination as! supportStepsViewController
    homeController.installer = installer
 }
}
```

I can't see too many solutions to this online, it seems to just be "make it all on one view controller". Is the only real other way to create another UITabBar Controller and double it up onto those "discover" and "contact us" pages?

Comment: Did you really put `func prepare` _inside_ `func homeSupportButton`? Should be outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present the Technical Support view controller (the one you've marked "On This Page") using Over Current Context modal presentation style:

[image]

and have the preceding view controller (the one you've marked "I want this TabBar") define that context:

[image]

Now the presented controller’s view doesn’t cover the tab bar.

Comment: Thank you for this! From what I can see, the segue is already set to “Present Modally”. Is this what you were referring to? The code im using to do this is; `@IBAction func homeSupportButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Home Support Pressed")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeSupport", sender: self)
        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let homeController = segue.destination as! supportStepsViewController
            homeController.installer = installer
        }
    }`

Comment: I know it’s a present modally segue. I’m telling you how to configure it so that it doesn’t cover the tab bar.

Comment: Sorry, read your comment wrong; can you take a quick look at the image below and let me know if this is correct as it still isnt working... https://i.imgur.com/GM4gW2P.png

Comment: Clarified with screen shots.